# Apache Spark - Memory Issue while writing Oracle table as parquet in S3

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory

In the current project, use  Spark to  read from Oracle table and Write  it as Parquet in S3.  As we have a source limitation of max 10 connection,  tables are read with single connection(numpartiton=1).  Below are the things that are done in Spark.

1. Read the Oracle Table
2. Add 3 new columns (Usually the record level metadata)
3. Write it as a Parquet in S3

Above logic is working for all the other tables  which are having more than 12Million records. Now  we are facing  memory issue(executor) for 1 particular oracle table , which has 2M records and one of the column is of BLOB type. From our investigation, we observed following.

1. There is no memory issues while writing to Parquet, when we exclude BLOB datatype column.
2. There is no memory issue when switching to AVRO format, all the columns in the table are
   written to S3 without any memory issue. But we cannot, go with this approach, as Parquet is
   the standard file format in the raw ingestion layer.

Apart from the above mentioned things, we tried to reduce the Fetch Size and increased NUM PARTITION. All the efforts were futile. Please suggest  solution to resolve the above  issue.

Comment: Reading the table into a single spark partition is very risky memory wise. Since there is blob type column, it sounds that this table is too big for reading with a single partition and that's why it causes OOM. How did you change NUM_PARTITIONS? please share your code.